# Cannot generate gradle.build files from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle

I have a project relying on the Facebook SDK, Google Play services and ZXing in Eclipse running nicely. I would like to get it into Android Studio but cannot export the `build.gradle` files.

Adt version is above 22, I have the latest SDK tools (including platform and build, versions 22.3, 19 and 19 respectively).

I have the option to generate gradle build files, select all of the projects, then hit next. On the final dialog with the projects that will have the modules exported I can only hit finish or cancel, and when I hit finish nothing happens, the dialog just sits there. :(

Has this happened to anyone before and what might be a possible solution? (I'm assuming the `gradle.build` files are supposed to be in the top level of each project directory, where the `.project`, res, src folders etc. reside. Is that right?)

Comment: This has happened to me and I ended up creating my own build.gradle file. I did not try and solve the issue with the generation of the build.gradle, instead created my own.

Then I imported the project into Android Studio and referenced the build.gradle file. I also setup the gradle wrapper too.

Comment: try generating gradle files only for the application project, the dependent library projects are taken care of and you dont have to export gradle files for those. Or try generating build.gradle for each project separately.

Comment: @Varun Yes that seemed to be the problem, removing the library references to the Facebook SDK and Play services of the project all together allows the gradle file to be produced.

Answer (score 0):

Generating build.gradle files **FIRST FOR ALL of the projects in my dependencies ONE AFTER ANOTHER** worked for me.

I generated build.gradle (with export wizrd for facebook, play and whatever other projects I imported and used in my project).